# Big-O notation for two simple recursive functions

Tags: python, algorithm, math, recursion, big-o

I have two recursive functions in Python and simply just want to know the Big O Notation for them.  What is the Big O for each these?

```
def cost(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return cost(n-1) + cost(n-1)

def cost(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return 2*cost(n-1)
```

Comment: I think the first is O(2^n) and the second is O(n)

Comment: I'd upvote that as an answer, if you explain how you arrived at those O's.

Comment: Likewise, Robert Harvey.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Let's use recurrence relations to solve this!  The first function's runtime can be described recursively as

> T(0) = 1
>
> T(n + 1) = 2T(n) + 1

That is, the base case takes one time unit to complete, and otherwise we make two recursive calls to smaller instances of the problem and do some amount of setup and cleanup work.  Expanding out some terms in this recurrence, we get

- T(0) = 1
- T(1) = 2T(0) + 1 = 2 + 1 = 3
- T(2) = 2T(1) + 1 = 2 × 3 + 1 = 7
- T(3) = 2T(2) + 1 = 2 × 7 + 1 = 15

This series 1, 3, 7, 15, ... might look familiar, since it's 2<sup>1</sup> - 1, 2<sup>2</sup> - 1, 2<sup>3</sup> - 1, etc.  More generally, we can prove that

> T(n) = 2<sup>n+1</sup> - 1

We can do this by induction.  As our base case, T(0) = 1 = 2<sup>1</sup> - 1, so the claim holds for n = 0.  Now assume that for some n that T(n) = 2<sup>n+1</sup> - 1.  Then we have that

> T(n + 1) = 2T(n) + 1 = 2(2<sup>n+1</sup> - 1) + 1 = 2<sup>n+2</sup> - 2 + 1 = 2<sup>n+2</sup> - 1

And we're done!  Since this recurrence works out to 2<sup>n+1</sup> - 1 = 2(2<sup>n</sup>) - 1, we have that the runtime is Θ(2<sup>n</sup>).

The second function's runtime can be described recursively as

> T(0) = 1
>
> T(n + 1) = T(n) + 1

Expanding out some terms:

- T(0) = 1
- T(1) = T(0) + 1 = 1 + 1 = 2
- T(2) = T(1) + 1 = 2 + 1 = 3
- T(3) = T(2) + 1 = 3 + 1 = 4

This gives 1, 2, 3, 4, ..., so more generally we might guess that

> T(n) = n + 1

We can prove this inductively again.  As a base case, if n = 0, then T(0) = 1 = 0 + 1.  For the inductive step, assume that for some n that T(n) = n + 1.  Then

> T(n + 1) = T(n) + 1 = n + 1 + 1 = n + 2

And we're done!  Since the runtime is n + 1, the runtime is Θ(n).

Hope this helps!

Comment: If you want, it seems fitting to add a note about memoization which can reduce the exponential runtime to linear

Comment: This is an epic answer. It helped a lot. Any way you can point me to something similar in terms of analyzing space ?

Comment: Great method! However I didn't fully understand this method until I read another site explaining the same recurrence relations you've described.
http://www.cs.duke.edu/~ola/ap/recurrence.html
Just putting the link here in case it helps anyone.

Answer (score 7):

**Finding cost using a recursion tree (through a visualize diagram).**

recurrence relation of the function cost(n)

```
                    T(n) = 2T(n-1)+c
```

[image]

```
If at kth level input size become 0 (base condition where func terminates)
                                           n-k =0
                                              k=n


Total cost of the function (adding cost of each level) :
             T(n) = 2^0*c+ 2^1*c + 2^2*c + 2^3*c +.. .. . .+ 2^n * c
                  = O(2^n)
```

similar way we can find the time complexity of second function.